# Что означает эта ошибка: [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 54ms?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

В консоли Google Chrome если выбрать уровень Verbose

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Начнем с того что это не ошибка.
Это предупреждение, избавление или неизбавление от которого на вашей совести.

Уровень "Verbose" в консоли позволяет проще находить узкие места в производительности, другими словами почему все так тупит. Обычно это код который поставленную задачу решает, но можно сделать его значительно оптимальнее.

Так вот, одним из убийц производительности в js является неаккуратное манипулирование DOM, потому что можно вызвать перерисовку того что перерисовывать не надо. В тяжелом случае это так называемый [layout thrasing](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qeJV77jRJxAJ:https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ru).

В данном конкретном случае ворнинг говорит вам, что на js произошло что-то что повлекло за собой значительную перестройку структуры страницы без явной для отладчика причины и рассказывает сколько это заняло. Кстати это не обязательно плохо, бывает от этого сложно отказаться.

Для того чтобы понимать как и когда браузеры решают что-то перерисовать, что такое repaint и reflow, рекомендую познакомиться с [этой статьей](https://habrahabr.ru/post/224187/).

В общем вам этим сообщением подсказывают цель для тюнинга производительности.

Comment: Сейчас кое что проверю и тогда поставлю галку.

Comment: @Khipster, видимо проверка не пройдена? =D

Comment: да всё руки не доходили. да, вы угадали это были крохотные манипуляции с dom. никак это не соптимизировать по-моему. кстати, на многих топ сайтах такое вылезает, на яндексе аж 5 таких предупреждений.

Comment: @Khipster, ага, как я писал - это не всегда плохо, это всего лишь подсказка