# Как узнать какая часть JS вызывает предупреждение forced reflow while executing javascript

Tags: javascript

Написал небольшое приложение на php+html+js+пару библиотек. Сделал появление popup. Popup подгружается через ajax. Добавил под popup блюр (повесил его на тег `<main>`). И хром начал вываливать иногда ошибку orced reflow while executing javascript. И появление popup иногда логает (на linux). На винде сильно тормозит. Как мне какой кусок кода тормозит или вызывает ошибку? Так же тормозят эффекты?

Код popup

```js
    let popup = {
     sUrl:'/project/searchAjax/',
     result: '',
     show:function(){
      // console.log('Popup open');
      if($('.pmc').length>0){
       $('.pmc').css({'display':'block'});
       $('.popup').fadeIn(800);
       $('.search_input').focus();
      }else{
       console.log('setPropDefult - false');
      }
     },
     close:function(){
      $('main').removeClass('custom_blur').addClass('custom_no_blur');
      $('.popup').fadeOut(800,function () {$('.pmc').css({'display':'none'});});
     },
     getVal:function(elements){
      let res = [], i = 0;
      for(i;i<elements.length;i++){
       res[i] = $(elements[i]).val();
      }
      return this.result=res;
      },
      post:function(ps){
      $.post(this.sUrl,{ps:ps},function(data){
       // console.log('Popup send post');
       $('.pagination').hide();
       $('.project_container').html(data);
       $('.loader-container').fadeOut(300,function(){$('.project_container').ready().ajaxComplete();});
       getAllComments();
       changePropertyBrons();
      });
      },
     send:function(){
      this.getVal($('select.psi_select.required.visible-bs'));
      let required = this.result;
      this.getVal($('select.psi_select.field.visible-bs'));
      let fields = this.result;
      let searchStr = $("input.search_input").val();
      let ps = [required,fields,searchStr];
      this.post(ps);
      $('main').removeClass('custom_blur').addClass('custom_no_blur');
      $('.popup').fadeOut(500,function(){$('.pmc').css({'display':'none'});});
      $('.loader-container').fadeIn(300);
      }
    };
    (function($){
     $(function(){
      "use strict";
      var val;
            $(document).on('click','.search_btn',function(){
                $('main').removeClass('custom_no_blur').addClass('custom_blur');
       if($('.pmc').length<1){
        let url = '/project/searchPopup/';
        $.post(url,function(data){
         $('header').after(data);
         popup.show();
         $('select[name="project-or-tools"]').on('change',function(){
          console.log('project-or-tools - change');
          val=this.value;
          switch(val){
           case 'project':
            if($('select[name="project-params"]').val()=='manager'){
             $("input.search_input").val('').prop("disabled",true);
             $('.manager-block').animate({height:'50',opacity:'1','padding': '5px 10px 5px 10px'},500);
             $('select[name="manager-params"]').addClass('visible-bs').removeClass('hide-bs');
            }
            else{$("input.search_input").prop("disabled",false);}
            $('.project-block').animate({height:'50',opacity:'1','padding': '5px 10px 5px 10px'},500);
            $('select[name="project-params"]').addClass('visible-bs').removeClass('hide-bs');
            $('.toolblock-block').animate({height:'0',opacity:'0','padding': '0'},500);
            $('select[name="toolblock-params"]').addClass('hide-bs').removeClass('visible-bs');
            $('.tool-block').animate({height:'0',opacity:'0','padding': '0'},500);
            $('select[name="tool-params"]').addClass('hide-bs').removeClass('visible-bs');
            $('.status-block').animate({height:'0',opacity:'0','padding': '0'},500);
            $('select[name="status-params"]').addClass('hide-bs').removeClass('visible-bs');
            break;
           case 'toolblock':
            $("input.search_input").val('').prop("disabled",true);
            $('.toolblock-block').animate({height:'50',opacity:'1','padding': '5px 10px 5px 10px'},500);
            $('select[name="toolblock-params"]').addClass('visible-bs').removeClass('hide-bs');
            $('.tool-block').animate({height:'50',opacity:'1','padding': '5px 10px 5px 10px'},500);
            $('select[name="tool-params"]').addClass('visible-bs').removeClass('hide-bs');
            $('.status-block').animate({height:'50',opacity:'1','padding': '5px 10px 5px 10px'},500);
            $('select[name="status-params"]').addClass('visible-bs').removeClass('hide-bs');
            $('.project-block').animate({height:'0',opacity:'0','padding': '0'},500);
            $('select[name="project-params"]').addClass('hide-bs').removeClass('visible-bs');
            $('.manager-block').animate({height:'0',opacity:'0','padding': '0'},500);
            $('select[name="manager-params"]').addClass('hide-bs').removeClass('visible-bs');
            break;
           default:
            $("input.search_input").prop("disabled",false);
            $('.toolblock-block').animate({height:'0',opacity:'0','padding': '0'},500);
            $('select[name="toolblock-params"]').addClass('hide-bs').removeClass('visible-bs');
            $('.tool-block').animate({height:'0',opacity:'0','padding': '0'},500);
            $('select[name="tool-params"]').addClass('hide-bs').removeClass('visible-bs');
            $('.status-block').animate({height:'0',opacity:'0','padding': '0'},500);
            $('select[name="status-params"]').addClass('hide-bs').removeClass('visible-bs');
            $('.project-block').animate({height:'0',opacity:'0','padding': '0'},500);
            $('select[name="project-params"]').addClass('hide-bs').removeClass('visible-bs');
            $('.manager-block').animate({height:'0',opacity:'0','padding': '0'},500);
            $('select[name="manager-params"]').addClass('hide-bs').removeClass('visible-bs');
            break;
          }
         });
         $('select[name="project-params"]').on('change',function(){
          // console.log('project-params - change');
          val=this.value;
          if(val=='manager'){
           $("input.search_input").val('').prop("disabled",true);
           $('.manager-block').animate({height:'50',opacity:'1','padding': '5px 10px 5px 10px'},500);
           $('select[name="manager-params"]').addClass('visible-bs').removeClass('hide-bs');
          }else{
           $("input.search_input").prop("disabled",false);
           $('.manager-block').animate({height:'0',opacity:'0','padding': '0'},500);
           $('select[name="manager-params"]').addClass('hide-bs').removeClass('visible-bs');
          }
         });
         $('select[name="toolblock-params"]').on('change',function(){
          // console.log('toolblock-params - change');
          if($('select[name="toolblock-params"]').val()!='none'){
           let toolblock=this.value;
           let url='/project/searchgetparams/';
           $.post(url,{toolblock:toolblock},function(data){
            $('select[name="tool-params"]').html(data);
           });
          }else{
           $('select[name="tool-params"]').html('<option value="none" selected>Выберите тип оборудования</option>');
          }

         });
         $('.popup__footer__submit').on('click',function(){
          let by=$('select[name="project-or-tools"]').val();
          if(by=='project'||by=='toolblock'){
           if(by=='project'){
            if($('select[name="project-params"]').val()=='none'){
             alert('Необходимо выбрать поле для поиска!')
            }else{popup.send();}
           }else{popup.send();}
          }else{alert('Вы не выбрали "Где искать"!');}
         });
         $('.pmc_close').on('click',popup.close);
         $('.popup_close').on('click',popup.close);
        });
       }else{
        popup.show();
       }
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <div class="pmc">
        <div class="pmc_close"></div>
        <div class="popup_container">
            <div class="popup">
                <div class="popup__navigation">
                    <div class="popup__navigation__search">
                        <input class="search_input" type="text" name="search_input" value="" placeholder="Ваш поисковый запрос" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup_close" title="Закрыть">
                        X
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="popup__search">
                    <div class="popup__search__item">
                        <select class="psi_select required visible-bs" name="project-or-tools">
                            <option value="0" selected>Не выбрано</option>
                            <option value="project">Проект</option>
                            <option value="toolblock">Оборудование</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup__search__item project-block" style="height:0;opacity:0;padding:0;">
                            <select class="hide-bs psi_select field" name="project-params">
                                <option value="none" selected>Выбрать поле поиска</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup__search__item manager-block" style="height:0;opacity:0;padding:0;">
                            <select class="hide-bs psi_select field" name="manager-params">
                                <option value="none" selected>Выбрать сотрудника</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup__search__item toolblock-block" style="height:0;opacity:0;padding:0;">

                            <select class="hide-bs psi_select field" name="toolblock-params">
                                <option value="none" selected>Выбрать тип оборудования</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup__search__item tool-block" style="height:0;opacity:0;padding:0;">
                        <select class="hide-bs psi_select field" name="tool-params">
                                <option value="none" selected>Выбрать поле поиска</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup__search__item status-block" style="height:0;opacity:0;padding:0;">
          
                            <select class="hide-bs psi_select field" name="status-params">
                                <option value="0" selected>Не учитывать статус</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup__search__item sort-block">
                        <select class="psi_select required visible-bs" name="sort-params">
                                <option value="ASC" selected>По возрастанию</option>
                                <option value="DESC">По убыванию</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup__search__item count-block">
                        <select class="psi_select required visible-bs" name="count-params">
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="30" selected>30</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                            <option value="100">100</option>
                            <option value="infinity">Все</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="popup__footer">
                    <div class="popup__footer__item">
                        <input class="popup__footer__submit" type="button" name="popup__footer__submit" value="Найти">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676115/Что-означает-эта-ошибка-violation-forced-reflow-while-executing-javascript-to оптимизировать нужно

Comment: @ThisMan При клике на select вылетает предупреждение `[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.`  Переместил вставку popup в футер, warning типа `forced reflow while executing javascript` стало меньше.